# How to format the returned date input value from a jQuery datepicker in order to match mysql DATE field?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date

I have a form with a jQuery datepicker. I have set the date format to the European way: `dd-mm-yy` in order to make it look nice for the user. However this date value eventually needs to be formatted back in **PHP** to `yy-mm-dd` so that in can be stored in my **mysql DATE field**. Here is my code:

 
**Jquery:**

```
   $("document").ready(function(){

    $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        monthNames: ['januari', 'februari', 'maart', 'april', 'mei', 'juni',
                     'juli', 'augustus', 'september', 'oktober', 'november', 'december'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Zo', 'Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za'],
        dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
        });
});
```

Comment: One way: have a look at [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: There is a difference between what is readable nice and what is a MySQL date. You should display the date in the form that is normal where you come from (year-month-day or for example like in Norway day-month-year), and "translate" the date to MySQL-date format using PHP afterwards :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options (in some vague order of preference):

1. Use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the string:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO ... VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(:date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
   ```
2. Convert the string received from jQuery into a PHP [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

   ```php
   $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['date']);
   ```

   and then either:

   - obtain a suitable formatted string:

     ```php
     $date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
     ```
   - obtain the UNIX timestamp:

     ```php
     $timestamp = $dt->getTimestamp();
     ```

     which is then passed directly to MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function:

     ```sql
     INSERT INTO ... VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(:timestamp))
     ```
3. Manually manipulate the string into a valid literal:

   ```php
   $parts = explode('-', $_POST['date']);
   $date  = "$parts[2]-$parts[1]-$parts[0]";
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery UI's [`altFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) option to have datepicker send the date to the server in an alternate format. This requires an ID of an alternate field in the form, which can be hidden.

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    altField: '#actualDate',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

This frees you to show one date format to the user while sending the equivalent date in a date format compatible with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
// dd-mm-yy to yy-mm-dd
$date = explode('-',$_POST['date']);
$mysqlDate = $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0];
```