# Need to reformat date variable to match date function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, variables, date

I have searched high and low on how to do this.

I am using the following datepicker script. `http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/`

Unfortunately it formats the date like so `xx/xx/xxxx`. However, the `date` function in mysql saves the date like so `xxxx-xx-xx`. I used `str_replace` to replace the `/` to `-`. My deli-ma is trying to figure out now how to convert my variable `$editsentdate` from `xx-xx-xxxx` to the mysql `date` format `xxxx-xx-xx`. When I just send the variable to my DB like it is it stores it as `0000-00-00` which I am sure is b/c that it is not formatted by `Ymd`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$editsentdate = str_replace('/','-',$_POST['edit_sent_date']); // xx-xx-xxxx
```

Comment: Searched so hard that you couldn't find any of the myriad of duplicates such as [How to format the returned date input value from a jQuery datepicker in order to match mysql DATE field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123305/how-to-format-the-returned-date-input-value-from-a-jquery-datepicker-in-order-to)

Comment: Are you having a bad day? Forgive me your highness for not finding that. Man, you should really contribute and not scorn people for not finding something... Wouldn't it make more since for me to find the answer (if I can) rather than posting?

Comment: When you've quite finished being facetious, your question is asked and answered here on SO several times each day, so you clearly didn't look very hard either here on SO or in the PHP documentation. As for my contributions, I regularly answer questions that aren't constantly being asked again and again, and which aren't so easy for people to find the answers, as witnessed by my reputation score; and I've contributed in other ways by developing open source libraries for use by other developers, and contributed to PHP core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's function `date()`. Example: `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['edit_sent_date']))`

Comment: No problem, keep in mind you shouldn't completely trust user input like this. You should first check if `strtotime() === false` - if it's false, it's a bad (or unknown) date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
$editsentdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['edit_sent_date']));
```

Answer (score 0):

In datepicker, you can format the date

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

More info [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUI%2FDatepicker%26redirect%3Dno#option-dateFormat)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a createFromFormat function in PHP. You could initiliaze the date and then format it any way you want.

See [PHP - DateTime createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysql_date = preg_replace('~^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$~',
    '$3-$2-$1', $_POST['edit_sent_date']);
```

**Assuming the date format is reliable**. Other answers might be more reliable but this is a different way... just FYI.

Comment: bit extreme for a simple solution. you might want to remove it before someone marks you  down.

Comment: @amigura I don't roll like that. This is 1 function call vs. 2. Might help the poster get into RegExp. Just because it's hard for you does not mean it's hard for everyone.

Comment: i was giving you friendly advice as RegExp was unnecessary, but ok.